# What causes a magnet to heat up?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, temperature, dissipation

In uses such as an electric motor, what would cause a magnet e.g. Neodymium, to heat up? Is it eddy currents or heat transfer from the electromagnets via radiation and convection?

Comment: the following may help http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/electrical-motor-heat-loss-d_898.html

Answer (score 2):

The motor you mention is a permanent magnet motor, therefore DC is being applied.  This eliminated eddy currents as a source.  As current passes through the coils, they heat up.  This heat is transferred to the surroundings (radiation, transmission, & convection), of which, the magnets are a part of.

Comment: So the magnet is purely subject to external heating from it's perspective? No internal heat generation

Comment: There is no such thing as a "DC motor", when one goes into details. In all types of motors the DC is converted into AC one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

A permanent magnet motor design would try to minimize the variability of the field near the magnet, but some variability and associated Eddy currents, as well as magnetic hysteresis loses, are always present.

On the other hand, the loses (i.e. heating) in such a motor are usually dominated by the ohmic heating of the coils. At some high RPM, the coil core loses will probably take their share as well.